# Scientific Linux install ISO hashes?

Tags: scientific-linux

So there are:

```
https://www.scientificlinux.org/distributions/6x/61/
```

hashes, but not for the latest:

```
SL-61-x86_64-2011-11-09-Install-DVD.iso
```

Where can I find up-to-date hashes for it? [of course over HTTPS, not FTP or HTTP!!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an e-mail to the websites admin, and:

https://www.scientificlinux.org/distributions/6x/61/

they updated the hashes!! :)

```
x86_64:
README x86_64 ISO Images
SL-61-x86_64-2011-07-27-boot.iso - sha1sum - cc2ef3a14493910c31598bf78c3523f722f6494e
SL-61-x86_64-2011-11-09-Everything-DVD1.iso - sha1sum - 3a6976c48cbad8a0e16ef902b176d5bc8e57b2c5
SL-61-x86_64-2011-07-27-Everything-DVD2.iso - sha1sum - 0dd829f14bd32be0bb6be5feedfd97062fe45b58
SL-61-x86_64-2011-11-09-Install-DVD.iso - sha1sum - fdd8bf7c0f80522015251137696676eb63a835bd
SL-61-x86_64-2011-07-27-LiveCD.iso - sha1sum - 2d9d09dc391c8283612adcde931029a327f6fe55
SL-61-x86_64-2011-07-27-LiveDVD.iso - sha1sum - 5fb0f7c94ca33f418eb64a64afad034dc6ab6037
SL-61-x86_64-2011-07-27-LiveMiniCD.iso - sha1sum - b1d528120e839f542c29e54b95780d48f7bde6d8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got it from, e.g, http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.1/x86_64/iso/,

you'll find [there a file called `SHA256SUM`](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.1/x86_64/iso/SHA256SUM) ([beside `SHA1SUM`](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.1/x86_64/iso/SHA1SUM)) containing your hashes:

```
941dd2bffc361204efeb786bc978ed92a91c76bbdba617f4014666c7b133b3e1  SL-61-x86_64-2011-11-09-Install-DVD.iso
```

and

```
fdd8bf7c0f80522015251137696676eb63a835bd  SL-61-x86_64-2011-11-09-Install-DVD.iso
```

respectively.

Comment: of course over HTTPS, not FTP or HTTP!!